# Draw projectile to canvas and shoot it in direction that the player is facing?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I've made a program that creates a player and allows it to move, and rotate. Now I want to bind Space to make a small projectile that shoots in the direction that the player is facing.

So far I have this function, called shoot(), that is supposed to draw this little circle at the player's position. Here's what it looks like:

```
      shoot() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.X, this.Y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.fill();
      },
```

But nothing is being drawn to the canvas, and no errors pop up in console. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? In addition, I'd like it to ACTUALLY shoot like I wanted it.

Full Code:

```
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.style = "position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; margin: auto; border: 0px";

    const kbd = {
      ArrowLeft: false, 
      ArrowUp: false, 
      ArrowRight: false,
      ArrowDown: false,
      Space: false,
    };

    const ship = {
      angle: 0,
      color: "white",
      x: canvas.width / 2,
      y: canvas.height / 2,
      width: 10,
      height: 12,
      drag: 0.9,
      accSpeed: 0.025,
      rotSpeed: 0.007,
      rotv: 0,
      ax: 0,
      ay: 0,
      vx: 0,
      vy: 0,
      rotateLeft() {
        this.rotv -= this.rotSpeed;
      },
      rotateRight() {
        this.rotv += this.rotSpeed;
      },
      accelerate() {
        this.ax += this.accSpeed;
        this.ay += this.accSpeed;
      },
      decelerate() {
        this.ax -= this.accSpeed;
        this.ay -= this.accSpeed;
      },
      shoot() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.X, this.Y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.fill();
      },
      move() {
        this.angle += this.rotv;
        this.rotv *= this.drag;
        this.vx += this.ax;
        this.vy += this.ay;
        this.ax *= this.drag;
        this.ay *= this.drag;
        this.vx *= this.drag;
        this.vy *= this.drag;
        this.x += Math.cos(this.angle) * this.vx;
        this.y += Math.sin(this.angle) * this.vy;
      },
      draw(ctx) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
        ctx.rotate(this.angle);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(this.height, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(-this.height, this.width);
        ctx.lineTo(-this.height, -this.width);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
      if (event.code in kbd) {
        event.preventDefault();
        kbd[event.code] = true;
      }
    });
    document.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
      if (event.code in kbd) {
        event.preventDefault();
        kbd[event.code] = false; 
      }
    });

    (function update() {
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  

      const shipActions = {
        ArrowLeft: "rotateLeft",
        ArrowUp: "accelerate",
        ArrowDown: "decelerate",
        ArrowRight: "rotateRight",
        Space: "shoot",
      };

      for (const key in shipActions) {
        if (kbd[key]) {
          ship[shipActions[key]]();
        }
      }
      
      ship.move();
      ship.draw(ctx);
      requestAnimationFrame(update);
    })();
```

Comment: `ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` clears your canvas you have to draw this projectile every time you draw everything else

Comment: @KonradLinkowski How can I update it so that it doesn't clear the projectile?

Comment: Add to the array of projectiles and then draw every element in that array

Comment: @KonradLinkowski is it possible to do the same thing that the ship does, drawing it to the canvas instead?

Comment: You are calling `ship.draw(ctx)` every frame so yes

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Your solution worked (arrays), however how do i make it so that you can't hold down space and create this mess to the canvas? https://streamable.com/4sxa6q

Comment: The idea is a bit more involved than pushing the bullets onto an array and drawing them (although that's a good start). You'll need to set their angle to be the same as the ship's ange on creation, then move them in that direction on each step. They probably don't need drag or acceleration, but it's otherwise the same as `move()`.